# Query multiple not related tables in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have more than 50 tables that are not related but all of them have a "Name" field, I want to query "John" and get all Johns in the different tables and store each row in an array (Javascript) for example:

```
arr['table1']="results if any"
arr["table2"]="results if any".
```

What I'm doing right now is a for loop for each table: 
 `SELECT * from tablesNameArray[i] WHERE name="John",` 
but I'm really wondering if there is any other better or "more" correct way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have 50+ tables like this? It sounds like you haven't organized your database properly.

Comment: MySQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single query using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE name = 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE name = 'John'
...
```

You can construct the query dynamically from the array:

```
sql = tablesNameArray.map(table => `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE name = 'John'`).join(" SELECT ALL ");
```

Comment: The `*` in the select list will only work if the number of columns returned by each SELECT is the same... otherwise, the query will return an error.

Comment: @spencer7593 Since the OP is using `SELECT *` in his query, I assumed all the tables are similar, and this is just one of those poorly designed databases where they created lots of identical tables.

Comment: I get you. Creating more than 50 identical tables, and then writing a query to get a single combined resultset from all of those tables. What would compel someone to do something like that? No earthly force. There must be some dark spiritual forces at work, conjured from the netherworld by sorcery or witchcraft. (We can foil the nefarious workings of the demonic forces ... `ALTER TABLE table42 ADD fubar TINYINT COMMENT 'ha!'`

Comment: @spencer7593 Come on, you must have seen questions from people who create a table for each customer, or each store, etc.?

Comment: ... and status reports (posing as questions) ... "my query doesn't work"

Comment: @Barmar the databases are not related, for example chefsTable(name, bestDish, workAt, hasOwnRestaurant, etc), footballPlayersTable(name, goalsTotal, isActive, currentTeam, lastTeam, etc), movieActors(name, lastMovie, age, height, country, salary, etc).

Comment: @dPow Why would you want to search unrelated tables like that?

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting to get from this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use joins. See [the join docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), MySQL in this case.

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.name = table3.name
WHERE table1.name = "John";
```

A left join will still select from the first table even if the joined table doesn't have a matching row -- you'll get `NULL` in the second table's selected columns for those rows which didn't match.

However, depending on your requirements, this is possibly no good -- I believe it won't grab rows from table2 or table3 where there's no corresponding row for that user in table1.

As pointed out by @spencer7593 in a comment below, you should probably only do this if you're certain the `name` column is unique within each table, otherwise you could be generating some ridiculously huge result sets.

Comment: I don't think using joins is necessary. That is, I disagree with the "you'll need to" statement. Yes, we could make use of joins. But this approach has the potential to generate a huge result set. If each of the 50 tables has exacty two rows with `name = 'John'`, the resultset is going to have, doing some quick math here, exactly 2^50 rows. That's over (one million x one billion) rows. If we have a guarantee that `name` is unique in each table, then this isn't a problem. But in the more general case, we need to beware of generating hugh jass resultsets..

Comment: You're right, that was a bad turn of phrase. Also about the rest. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: the downvote wasn't from me, i didn't downvote. if there is a unique constraint on `name`, in each of the 50 tables, then i would opt for the join pattern. I'd use an inline view to return exactly one row, then use outer joins for each of the 50 tables, for the join condition I would compare the name column to a literal, like this: `SELECT t1.name AS t1_name, t2.name AS t2_name, ... FROM ( SELECT 1 ) i LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.name = 'John' LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.name = 'John' ...` is how I would do it.  +10